# Matplotlib: How to plot multiple datasets on the same subplot(s)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, netcdf

thank you in advance for assistance with this issue. I have been working tirelessly to get this working, but as a non-expert I've found myself stuck with the following issue.

Goal: I would like to plot both datasets, NOAA surface flask measurement data (.csv) and GEOS-Chem GCHP data (.nc4), on the same system of subplots such to compare the efficacy of my GEOS-Chem GCHP run output. For the sake of simplicity, I will provide information to plot at three separate observation sites (instead of the 15 I am trying to work with):

Here is all of the information I believe you'll need:

**Metadata for each dataset at each site, all of which will be in dataframes:**

```
GCHP:
-----

# For Alert, Nunavut, Canada Observation Site (ALT)
DF_ALT = 
             lon   lat  lev  SpeciesConc_C2H6
time                                         
2018-01-01 -65.0  82.0  1.0       1609.727295
2018-02-01 -65.0  82.0  1.0       1823.014893
2018-03-01 -65.0  82.0  1.0       2023.412964
2018-04-01 -65.0  82.0  1.0       1669.494263
2018-05-01 -65.0  82.0  1.0       1246.383545
2018-06-01 -65.0  82.0  1.0       1002.191650

# For Anmyeon-do, Taean, South Korea Observation Site (AMY)
DF_AMY = 
              lon   lat  lev  SpeciesConc_C2H6
time                                          
2018-01-01  125.0  38.0  1.0       2449.527344
2018-02-01  125.0  38.0  1.0       2539.914307
2018-03-01  125.0  38.0  1.0       3119.644043
2018-04-01  125.0  38.0  1.0       2959.308350
2018-05-01  125.0  38.0  1.0       2604.787598
2018-06-01  125.0  38.0  1.0       2571.400879

# For Barrow, Alaska, United States Observation Site (BRW)
DF_BRW = 
              lon   lat  lev  SpeciesConc_C2H6
time                                          
2018-01-01 -155.0  70.0  1.0       1441.598267
2018-02-01 -155.0  70.0  1.0       1618.777588
2018-03-01 -155.0  70.0  1.0       1638.707397
2018-04-01 -155.0  70.0  1.0       1911.577148
2018-05-01 -155.0  70.0  1.0       1335.739624
2018-06-01 -155.0  70.0  1.0       1191.573242

NOAA:
-----

# For Alert, Nunavut, Canada Observation Site (ALT)
NOAA_BRW_Data = 
 site      decdate  yyyymmdd  HH:MM  wind_dir  ...  flag  instr.   lat  long elev
0   ALT  2018.007159  20180103  14:43     225.0  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
1   ALT  2018.105970  20180208  16:18     244.6  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
2   ALT  2018.144269  20180222  15:48     161.2  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
3   ALT  2018.160588  20180228  14:45      79.8  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
4   ALT  2018.275559  20180411  13:54     296.3  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
5   ALT  2018.316754  20180426  14:46     237.2  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
6   ALT  2018.333183  20180502  14:41     192.3  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
7   ALT  2018.352392  20180509  14:57     183.3  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
8   ALT  2018.390845  20180523  15:48     314.9  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
9   ALT  2018.448428  20180613  16:14     349.7  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
10  ALT  2018.467369  20180620  14:09     288.2  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
11  ALT  2018.511338  20180706  15:19     207.6  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
12  ALT  2018.524939  20180711  14:28     266.8  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
13  ALT  2018.544258  20180718  15:42     202.0  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
14  ALT  2018.588312  20180803  17:37     192.9  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
15  ALT  2018.623508  20180816  13:56     202.0  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
16  ALT  2018.659471  20180829  16:58     239.7  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
17  ALT  2018.697607  20180912  15:02     150.5  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
18  ALT  2018.722342  20180921  15:43     185.6  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
19  ALT  2018.735900  20180926  14:29     221.4  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
20  ALT  2018.755194  20181003  15:30     180.0  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
21  ALT  2018.774326  20181010  15:06     233.4  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
22  ALT  2018.831979  20181031  16:08     234.7  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
23  ALT  2018.851551  20181107  19:35     340.5  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
24  ALT  2018.870420  20181114  16:53     205.6  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210
25  ALT  2018.952494  20181214  15:51     236.2  ...     -     PR1  82.5 -62.3  210

# For Anmyeon-do, Taean, South Korea Observation Site (AMY)
NOAA_AMY_Data = 
  site      decdate  yyyymmdd HH:MM  ...  instr.      lat      long  elev
0  AMY  2018.101713  20180207  5:27  ...     PR1  36.5389  126.3295    47
1  AMY  2018.194578  20180313  0:30  ...     PR1  36.5389  126.3295    47
2  AMY  2018.293995  20180418  7:24  ...     PR1  36.5389  126.3295    47
3  AMY  2018.348640  20180508  6:05  ...     PR1  36.5389  126.3295    47
4  AMY  2018.581387  20180620  4:57  ...     PR1  36.5389  126.3295    47
5  AMY  2018.754064  20180921  6:54  ...     PR1  36.5389  126.3295    47
6  AMY  2018.987148  20181227  7:25  ...     PR1  36.5389  126.3295    47

# For Barrow, Alaska, United States Observation Site (BRW)
NOAA_BRW_Data = 
   site      decdate  yyyymmdd  HH:MM  wind_dir  ...  flag  instr.   lat   long elev
0   BRW  2018.089968  20180202  20:07     263.5  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
1   BRW  2018.232740  20180326  22:48     102.6  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
2   BRW  2018.251680  20180402  20:43      77.3  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
3   BRW  2018.320607  20180428   0:31      98.0  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
4   BRW  2018.350112  20180508  18:59     107.0  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
5   BRW  2018.366625  20180514  19:38     117.6  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
6   BRW  2018.385662  20180521  18:24      74.2  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
7   BRW  2018.424220  20180604  20:10      56.7  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
8   BRW  2018.454073  20180615  17:41     348.8  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
9   BRW  2018.484233  20180626  17:53      98.7  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
10  BRW  2018.511731  20180706  18:46     248.8  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
11  BRW  2018.531060  20180713  20:05     240.7  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
12  BRW  2018.550152  20180720  19:20     254.4  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
13  BRW  2018.569806  20180727  23:30      99.6  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
14  BRW  2018.580188  20180731  18:27      93.5  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
15  BRW  2018.602256  20180808  19:46      73.9  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
16  BRW  2018.626684  20180817  17:45     350.4  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
17  BRW  2018.635048  20180820  19:01      71.0  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
18  BRW  2018.654172  20180827  18:33      79.9  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
19  BRW  2018.692542  20180910  18:40     120.5  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
20  BRW  2018.711615  20180917  17:45     120.2  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
21  BRW  2018.750063  20181001  18:33     103.9  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
22  BRW  2018.774829  20181010  19:30      76.1  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
23  BRW  2018.788387  20181015  18:16      72.2  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
24  BRW  2018.819085  20181026  23:11       1.3  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
25  BRW  2018.857485  20181109  23:34     166.6  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
26  BRW  2018.876261  20181116  20:03     106.5  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
27  BRW  2018.884349  20181119  18:54      69.5  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
28  BRW  2018.903824  20181126  21:30      61.4  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
29  BRW  2018.934161  20181207  23:15     270.3  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
30  BRW  2018.942057  20181210  20:25      60.9  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
31  BRW  2018.972217  20181221  20:37     -99.0  ...     -     PR1  71.3 -156.6    8
```

**Body of Python Script:**

```
# Key Module Import(s)
import os
import csv # Module which enables the script to work directly with .csv files, in this case being the NOAA and INSTAAR Observation Data
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime


# Specification of Latitude, Longitude, and Elevation of Target Grid Cell corresponding to the Key Observation Sites:

# For Alert, Nunavut, Canada Observation Site (ALT)
Lat_ALT = 82.4508
Lon_ALT = -62.5072
elev_ALT = 210

# For Anmyeon-do, Taean, South Korea Observation Site (AMY) - (C2H6 Terminated in 2019-04-02)
Lat_AMY = 36.5389
Lon_AMY = 126.3295
elev_AMY = 47

# For Barrow, Alaska, United States Observation Site (BRW)
Lat_BRW = 71.31
Lon_BRW = -156.58
elev_BRW = 8

GCHP_OutDir = ('/PSU/CCAR REU/Emission(s) Inventories (GEOS-CHEM)/GEOS-Chem Output Directory/Baseline Simulation/baseline_c24_2018/') # GCHP C2H6 Output Directory

FN_01 = (GCHP_OutDir + 'GEOSChem.SpeciesConcMonthlyAvg.20180101_0000z.nc4') # Location of Monthly Average of C2H6 GCHP Output file for 01/2018
FN_02 = (GCHP_OutDir + 'GEOSChem.SpeciesConcMonthlyAvg.20180201_0000z.nc4') # Location of Monthly Average of C2H6 GCHP Output file for 02/2018
FN_03 = (GCHP_OutDir + 'GEOSChem.SpeciesConcMonthlyAvg.20180301_0000z.nc4') # Location of Monthly Average of C2H6 GCHP Output file for 03/2018
FN_04 = (GCHP_OutDir + 'GEOSChem.SpeciesConcMonthlyAvg.20180401_0000z.nc4') # Location of Monthly Average of C2H6 GCHP Output file for 04/2018
FN_05 = (GCHP_OutDir + 'GEOSChem.SpeciesConcMonthlyAvg.20180501_0000z.nc4') # Location of Monthly Average of C2H6 GCHP Output file for 05/2018
FN_06 = (GCHP_OutDir + 'GEOSChem.SpeciesConcMonthlyAvg.20180601_0000z.nc4') # Location of Monthly Average of C2H6 GCHP Output file for 06/2018

# Preliminary Steps - Parametrize:

FN_ALL_List = [FN_01, FN_02, FN_03, FN_04, FN_05, FN_06] # List of all of the Monthly AVG C2H6 GCHP Data
DS_ALL = xr.open_mfdataset(FN_ALL_List) # Opens all 6 datasets as 1 through xarray
DS_ALL *= 1e12 # v/v -> pptv (Conversion of original units mol mol^-1 dry to units of pptv)
DS_ALL.attrs['units'] = 'pptv'
C2H6_C = DS_ALL['SpeciesConc_C2H6']

# GCHP Data Selection at each Observation site:

C2H6_C_ALT = C2H6_C.sel(lat = Lat_ALT, lon = Lon_ALT, lev = 0, method = 'nearest') # Data selection from relative AMY coordinates @ lev(0) = Surface
C2H6_C_AMY = C2H6_C.sel(lat = Lat_AMY, lon = Lon_AMY, lev = 0, method = 'nearest') # Data selection from relative AMY coordinates @ lev(0) = Surface
C2H6_C_BRW = C2H6_C.sel(lat = Lat_BRW, lon = Lon_BRW, lev = 0, method = 'nearest') # Data selection from relative AMY coordinates @ lev(0) = Surface

# Read C2H6_C_GCHP Datasets Sel.Datasets into Pandas Dataframes:

DF_ALT = C2H6_C_ALT.to_dataframe()
DF_AMY = C2H6_C_AMY.to_dataframe()
DF_BRW = C2H6_C_BRW.to_dataframe()

# Location of NOAA & INSTAAR Observational Data CSV's:

NOAA_ObsDIR = ('E:/PSU/CCAR REU/Emission(s) Inventories (GEOS-CHEM)/Observation Data/Observation Data - NOAA/') # NOAA Observational C2H6 Data Directory

NOAA_ALT = (NOAA_ObsDIR + 'ALT_NOAA_Observations_2018.csv') # Location of NOAA Observational C2H6 Data at ALT in 2018
NOAA_AMY = (NOAA_ObsDIR + 'AMY_NOAA_Observations_2018.csv') # Location of NOAA Observational C2H6 Data at AMY in 2018
NOAA_BRW = (NOAA_ObsDIR + 'BRW_NOAA_Observations_2018.csv') # Location of NOAA Observational C2H6 Data at BRW in 2018

# Read into Dataframe: Target_Columns = ['decdate', 'C2H6_C', 'C2H6_sd']

NOAA_ALT_Data = pd.read_csv(NOAA_ALT, sep = ",", skipinitialspace = True) # Initiation of ALT_NOAA_Obs_2018.csv
NOAA_AMY_Data = pd.read_csv(NOAA_AMY, sep = ",", skipinitialspace = True) # Initiation of AMY_NOAA_Obs_2018.csv
NOAA_BRW_Data = pd.read_csv(NOAA_BRW, sep = ",", skipinitialspace = True) # Initiation of BRW_NOAA_Obs_2018.csv

# Cross-plot of each of the GCHP and NOAA subplot(s) at each Key NOAA Observation Sites:

nrow = 2 # Definition of the number of rows for the subplots
ncol = 0 # Definition of the number of columns for the subplots
figsize = ('all') # Definition of the size of each of the figures (subplots)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol, figsize, dpi = 200) # Subplotting parameters
plt.rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = -10
plt.rcParams['axes.titlelocation'] = 'center'
plt.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 7.5
plt.rcParams['axes.titleweight'] = 'bold'
plt.rcParams['axes.grid.axis'] = 'both'
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 3
plt.rcParams['axes.labelweight'] = 'bold'
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 3
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 3

# Replot ALL of subplot(s):

NOAA_ALT_Data.plot(y = ('C2H6_C'), ax = axes[0,0], title = "BRW", legend = None, linestyle = 'dashed', color = 'green')
DF_ALT.plot(y = ('SpeciesConc_C2H6'), ax = axes[0,0], color = 'green', legend = None)
axes[0,0].set_title("ALT", fontsize = 7.5)
axes[0,0].grid(True)
axes[0,0].set_xlabel("")
axes[0,0].set_xlim(xmin = 20180101, xmax = 20180601)

NOAA_AMY_Data.plot(y = ('C2H6_C'), ax = axes[1,0], title = "AMY", legend = None,  linestyle = 'dashed', color = 'blue')
DF_AMY.plot(y = ('SpeciesConc_C2H6'), ax = axes[1,0], color = 'blue', legend = None)
axes[1,0].set_title("AMY", fontsize = 7.5)
axes[1,0].grid(True)
axes[1,0].set_xlabel("")
axes[1,0].set_xlim(xmin = 20180101, xmax = 20180601)

NOAA_BRW_Data.plot(y = ('C2H6_C'), ax = axes[2,0], title = "BRW", legend = None, linestyle = 'dashed', color = 'yellow')
DF_BRW.plot(y = ('SpeciesConc_C2H6'), ax = axes[2,0], color = 'yellow', legend = None)
axes[2,0].set_title("BRW", fontsize = 7.5)
axes[2,0].grid(True)
axes[2,0].set_xlabel("")
axes[2,0].set_xlim(xmin = 20180101, xmax = 20180601)
```

ValueError: Date ordinal 20180101.0 converts to 57221-03-29T00:00:00.000000 (using epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00), but Matplotlib dates must be between year 0001 and 9999.

Here is my output, please keep in mind that this is a screenshot of my 15-subplot output--i.e. ignore CGO and what should be 'HFM':
[Output error for cross-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCczE.png)

My hunch is that it has to do with the different time format(s), i.e. GCHP: yyyy-mm--dd and NOAA: 2018.007159 (decdate). **At this point, I am unsure what I can do to correct for this. ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Once again, thanks in advance and kind regards!**

Comment: Convert the `yyyymmdd` column from your NOAA dataframe to datetimes with `pd.to_datetime()`.

Comment: It looks like `yyyymmdd` is a float column (`20180101.0`), probably because there may be missing dates, which adds `np.nan`. You can dropna on that column, then try to convert it to a datetime dtype with `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: When you set the `axes[0,0].set_xlim(xmin = 20180101, xmax = 20180601)` it needs to be `'2018-01-01'` and `'2018-06-01'`

Comment: For `NOAA_BRW_Data`, after converting `yyyymmdd` to a datetime dtype, you need to set it as the index with `NOAA_BRW_Data = NOAA_BRW_Data.set_index('yyyymmdd')`. This will make it like the other dataframes and it will plot correctly with the index as the xaxis. Otherwise you need to change the plots and specify `x='yyyymmdd'`

Comment: Thank you both very much, this help was much appreciated. Specifically @TrentonMcKinney , I wanted to confirm the order of operations you mentioned. How does this script look:

NOAA_BRW_Data.dropna(subset = ['yyyymmdd']) -->

pd.to_datetime(NOAA_BRW_Data['yyyymmdd'], format = '%Y%m%d') -->

NOAA_BRW_Data = NOAA_BRW_Data.set_index('yyyymmdd')

Comment: That looks right to me. You may need to play around with it to make sure everything is working

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney - Unfortunately, this method appears to not work. I will continue to play around with formatting. Any additional ideas would of course be appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: UPDATE - The method did work! There was an error initially when using: I had missed this component --> pd.read_csv(NOAA_BRW_Data, . . ., parse_dates = ['yyyymmdd'] ), as since I am reading directly in from a .csv file this is required. Thank you again!